# Smooth animation WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, wpf-animation

I have an animation that is making an image wheel rotate forever. Here is my code:

```
<Image Name="BigWheelImage"  
               Source="{DynamicResource BigWheel}" 
               Height="400" 
               Width="400" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform 
                    CenterX="200" 
                    CenterY="200" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Image.IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" DesiredFrameRate="30">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                From="360" To="0" Duration="0:0:35" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

But when I run the application, the wheel is not rotating smoothly. It "jumps". I tried to modify the `DesiredFrameRated` as I read [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/06/13/wpf-reducing-cpu-consumption-for-animations/), but with no luck.

Any idea on how to make the animation look smoothly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *jumps*, but when using your code, I didn't see any jumps. It seems pretty smooth to me already. Either way, there is no 'Smooth' property that you can adjust... if the CPU is busy on any other work, then the UI updates will suffer.

Comment: Hummmm I'm gonna check. Maybe this machine is too busy...

Comment: You might consider to update your GPU / your graphics card. CPU has not much to do in wpf since wpf was designed to use GPU.